# XDMCP is slow any ideas? (looking for alternative remote desktops)

Tags: linux, unix, performance, remote-desktop, x-windows

I've been used to using RDP on Windows to remote to machines, and I've got an asus eee 701 which I want to use to do some *nix programming on. While the eee is a lovely little machine the screen and keyboard are a little small to use for lots of programming.

I've tried using Xming (the free version) to remote login into the eee from my desktop using XDMCP (or even using a ssh session as a straight X11 server and no desktop on the eee) the whole thing seems seriously slow over wifi the initial desktop takes at least 5 seconds to paint (might even be 10 seconds I haven't actually timed it).

So my real question is what do other folks use for remote control with a GUI for their *nix boxes? I am finding it hard to believe the performance is so bad over a wifi network (It makes the Mac IIs I used to use a college in 1988 seem fast) or is this just a problem with Xming and using say the Cygwin X11 server would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want performance, security and flexibility, i suggest takeing a look at nx - nomachine.com has a good windows client, and the freenx server will work on the server side

Comment: Thanks that looks like it's worth a go, it reads like it will sort out my basic performance problems (mind you calling a eee701 a server is a bit of stretch).

Comment: i used it on a PII 450 with 640 mb of ram. And that WAS my server until 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly remote desktop, but it'll work;

www.tridiavnc.com

it is inherently unsecure, but if you control when you are using it, and don't open the port on your router, you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [X11 Forwarding using SSH](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/XDMCP-HOWTO/ssh.html)? I have used this with much satisfaction in the past.

Comment: Tried this still poor perf.